# Why does Oracle not find oci.dll?

Tags: database, oracle, toad

I use `TOAD 10.2.1.3` under Windows7 and get the following error:

```
Cannot find OCI DLL: C:\Oracle\Product\11.2.0\oci.dll
```

that is strange because exact in the same path I can find `oci.dll`.
That is 64 bit system, that might not be the problem!
Any Idea?
I am thankful for every hint!

Comment: Is `C:\Oracle\Product\11.2.0` part of your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: No but if I put it there it dose not work at all, really strange! I have no idea!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Just wanted to come say that, adding the path variable to the oracle folder fixed this error for me

Comment: I also faced this issue. Its because of missing/wrong value in your PATH variable. Once you validate restart the services for Oracle and instance, will solve this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using TOAD, you will need to download the 32-bit version of the Oracle Client Tools.

Since the Client Tools are different on a per-processor architecture basis, you probably need to install versions.

Comment: How can I know which version of Oracle Client Tools I have?

Comment: You can check your registry. If Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_...` exists then you have a 64bit Oracle Client installed. If Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_...` exists then you have the 32 bit version.

Comment: well, thanks to all of you, I have  64bit! I have just     KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_..   Now the question how can I change it please?

Comment: In case you don't need the 64 bit client, you can de-install it and install the 32 bit client. In case you need both, follow this instruction: [Stack Overflow - Install Oracle x86 and x64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)

Comment: @maniA: I would recommend to install both since the one program needs the 64-bit version and the other the 32-bit version. Just download the client tools from the Oracle website.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that recent Oracle client installers change file permissions.

I had Oracle 12.0.1 32 bit client installed for a year.
I recently installed Oracle 12.0.1 64 bit client.
The Oracle install change ALL file permissions in the 32 bit folders.

My application suddenly failed to run.

I used PROCMON.EXE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/) and noticed that permission was denied opening OCI.DLL

I changed the permissions for everything in the Oracle client folders and application works as expected.

Comment: faced the very same issue. is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

I just installed Oracle Instant Client 18_3 with the SDK. The PATH and ENV variable is set as instructed on the install page but I get the OCl.dll not found error. I searched the entire drive recursively and no such DLL exists.

So now what?

With the [install instructions (not updated for 18_3)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E83411_01/OREAD/installing-oracle-database-instant-client.htm#OREAD348) and
[downloads](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) there are **MISTAKES at step 13**, so watch out for that.

When you create the folder structure for the downloads just write them the **old** way "c:\oraclient". Then when you unzip the basic, SDK and instant Client install for Windows 10_x64 extract them to "C:\oraclient\", because they **all** write to the same default folder. Then, when you set the ENV variable (which is no longer ORACLE_HOME, but now is OCI_LIB64) and the PATH, you will point to "C:\oraclient\instantclient_18_3".

To be sure you got it all right drill down and look for any duplicate "instantclient_18_3" folders. If you do have those cut and paste the CONTENTS to the root folder "C:\oraclient\instantclient_18_3\" folder.

Whoever works on the documentation at Oracle needs to troubleshoot better. 
I've seen "C:\oreclient_dir_install", "c:\oracle", "c:\oreclient" and "c:\oraclient" all mentioned as install directories, all for Windows x64 installs

BTW, install the C++ redist it helps.
[The 18.3 Basic package requires the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Redistributable.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003#bookmark-vs2013)

Answer (score 2):

if you use 64-bit pc, oracle doesn't compatible with it. Oracle doesn't find oci.dll file in 64-bit.

Therefore, you can try to change oracle home on the top. As a result of that, home path will change.

At least, I solved that error with changing path.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, I run 64 bit Windows and had downloaded the 64 bit TOAD package.
I finally arrived at the conclusion that it was because I unzipped the package in a windows share using cygwin command line unzip. Turned out TOAD wasn't liking the permissions on some files. When I unzipped using windows File Explorer everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the oracle folder to my environmental variables and that fixed my identical error

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for solving this issue. Maybe this answer will help someone.

In my case similar issue have appeared when I used `Oracle Instant Client 18.5` for connecting to DB using `Toad 13.1.1.5`

To solve it I've downloaded more recent version of OIC - `Oracle Instant Client 19.3` and Toad connected to Oracle's DB without issues.

Maybe there was version incompatibility issue. New version of Toad require a new version of oci library.

Both OICs were 64 bit and folders of both of them I've added into the user's Path variable.

Client OS: Win10

Server: OL7.7,

DB: 18c

Answer (score 0):

I was using SQLTool where I was getting oci.dll was not found then I downloaded instantclient-basic-nt-12.2.0.1.0 extracted it and added the folder till oci.dll file in path variable

eg.: Path: .;D:\Softwares\Oracle Instant Client\instantclient_12_2

It resolve my issue, now I am able to open the SQLTool

Answer (score 0):

Besides the many relevant and correct answers here, in my case I was also missing the *"Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package"*, which is needed by oci.dll and can be downloaded from microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows 10 x64.

I downloaded oracle client version 21.7 for windows x64 from [Oracle Offical Site](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html).

I fixed the Oci.DLL problem by installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported download for x64 from [Microsoft Offical Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)